# Eaton & Kortum - Technology, Geography, and Trade - How theta impacts geographical barrier

Tags: international-trade

The paper says:

> Smaller $\theta$ implies more heterogeneity, and thus larger
>   comparative advantage, and hence stronger force for trade relative to
>   resistance $d_{ni}$.

Would it be correct to therefore infer that geographical barriers are less important when $\theta$ is smaller? Or is this "technically incorrect"?

Comment: A link to the paper would be nice.